# Is there really a use to having separate [time] and [date-time] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I question the need for having separate [time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [date-time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time) tags. I think those concepts will rarely be distinct in terms of the questions we have here. What do you think? My inclination would be to merge [date-time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time) into [time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag currently has 17 questions, and [date-time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time) currently has 58. Neither of them have a tag wiki. They seem to be used for exactly the same purpose.

I think we should 1) make [date-time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time) a synonym of [time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), 2) add a tag wiki for [time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), 3) retag questions that don't follow the new tag wiki.

Comment: I did step one. I'll leave step 2 and 3 to the community.

Comment: What aspects of time will the tag cover? Everything from physics and GR concepts to calculating the time that the Sun rises tomorrow? It could be quite a challenging wiki to write!

Comment: @uhoh I think the tag should focus on time as a tool and not the concept of time in physics. That seems to be the bulk of the usage. I think space-time and the relativity tags cover the physics concepts pretty well.